# Como faço para apagar aquele elemento criado com js dentro de uma div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Eu quero que quando apertar o botão a nota em que o botão foi apertado seja apagada, ja tentei passaro "this" como parametro mas não vai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
let notescontainer = document.getElementById("notescontainer")

let criarnota = document.querySelectorAll("div.container button.but")[0]

criarnota.addEventListener("click", criarnovanota)

function criarnovanota (){
    notescontainer = document.getElementById("notescontainer")
    let nota = document.createElement("div")
    nota.setAttribute("class", "note")
    notescontainer.appendChild(nota)
    let titlenote = document.createElement("input")
    titlenote.setAttribute("type", "text")
    titlenote.setAttribute("class", "titlenote")
    titlenote.setAttribute("placeholder", "Titulo")
    nota.appendChild(titlenote)
    let textarea = document.createElement("textarea")
    textarea.setAttribute("name", "nota")
    textarea.setAttribute("class", "txt")
    textarea.setAttribute("cols", "40")
    textarea.setAttribute("rows", "8")
    nota.appendChild(textarea)
    let button = document.createElement("button")
    button.setAttribute("class", "del")
    button.setAttribute("onclick", "apagarnota(this)")
    // button.addEventListener("click", apagarnota(this))
    nota.appendChild(button)
    let img = document.createElement("img")
    img.setAttribute("class", "lixo")
    img.setAttribute("src", "./Imagen/lixeira.png")
    button.appendChild(img)
}

function apagarnota (){
    notescontainer.removeChild(this.nota)
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(46, 49, 49);
    color: white;

}


.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.title{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#notescontainer{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(46, 49, 49);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    /* display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 5px 5px;
    border: 2em black;
    grid-template-areas:
        ". . ."
        ". . ."
        ". . ."; */
    
}

.note, .noter{
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.txt{
    background-color: rgb(224, 221, 48);
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 208px;
}

textarea{
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

p{
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.titlenote{
    background-color: rgb(46, 49, 49);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.txt::placeholder{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.trocacor{
    display: none;
}

.lixo{
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Bloco de notas</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Bloco de notas</h1>
        <button class="but">Criar nota</button>
        <div id="notescontainer">
           
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perguntas com código tem que ter um [mcve] do problema de forma a visitantes com situação similar, mesmo leigos, identificarem o problema, e as respostas servirem para outras pessoas em outros contextos. Códigos específicos demais ou já aplicados só servem para o autor da pergunta, aí não cumprem a função do site. Mais detalhes em [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70) do site. O [FAQ da Comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/70) é um bom complemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está passando um parâmetro no uso da função no evento onclick do botão (button), no caso o `this`, que referencia o próprio elemento clicado, mas a sua função `apagarnota` não possui nenhum parâmetro definido.

Definindo um parâmetro na função e utilizando [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) para pegar a div com a classe note, que contém esse elemento clicado, será possível excluir essa div, confome código relevante modificado abaixo:

```
function apagarnota (el){
    notescontainer.removeChild(el.parentNode);
}
```

```js
let notescontainer = document.getElementById("notescontainer")

let criarnota = document.querySelectorAll("div.container button.but")[0]

criarnota.addEventListener("click", criarnovanota)

function criarnovanota (){
    notescontainer = document.getElementById("notescontainer")
    let nota = document.createElement("div")
    nota.setAttribute("class", "note")
    notescontainer.appendChild(nota)
    let titlenote = document.createElement("input")
    titlenote.setAttribute("type", "text")
    titlenote.setAttribute("class", "titlenote")
    titlenote.setAttribute("placeholder", "Titulo")
    nota.appendChild(titlenote)
    let textarea = document.createElement("textarea")
    textarea.setAttribute("name", "nota")
    textarea.setAttribute("class", "txt")
    textarea.setAttribute("cols", "40")
    textarea.setAttribute("rows", "8")
    nota.appendChild(textarea)
    let button = document.createElement("button")
    button.setAttribute("class", "del")
    button.setAttribute("onclick", "apagarnota(this)")
    // button.addEventListener("click", apagarnota(this))
    nota.appendChild(button)
    let img = document.createElement("img")
    img.setAttribute("class", "lixo")
    img.setAttribute("src", "./Imagen/lixeira.png")
    button.appendChild(img)
}

function apagarnota (el){
    notescontainer.removeChild(el.parentNode);
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(46, 49, 49);
    color: white;

}


.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.title{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#notescontainer{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(46, 49, 49);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    /* display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 5px 5px;
    border: 2em black;
    grid-template-areas:
        ". . ."
        ". . ."
        ". . ."; */
    
}

.note, .noter{
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.txt{
    background-color: rgb(224, 221, 48);
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 208px;
}

textarea{
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

p{
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.titlenote{
    background-color: rgb(46, 49, 49);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.txt::placeholder{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.trocacor{
    display: none;
}

.lixo{
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Bloco de notas</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Bloco de notas</h1>
        <button class="but">Criar nota</button>
        <div id="notescontainer">
           
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```